# JavaME FileConnection url

Tags: java, java-me, mobile-phones

I want to save data to my Sony Ericsson K750i. I know the phone implements FileConnection version 1.0. The list of roots taken from

```
FileSystemRegistry.listRoots();
```

returns single element named "c:/". I want to save a file.txt just about anywhere, but preferably to the memory stick attached. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. It throws an IOException without any message. I tried opening the fileconnection on numerous roots like c:/, C:/, /, ./, root1/, SDCard/, CFCard/, MemoryStick/ and perhaps some more but without any luck.

The exception is thrown right after this line for any of those roots:

```
FileConnection filecon = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///MemoryStick/file.txt");
```

Please, what URL should i use?

Comment: Try listing the files in one of the roots, get hold of one of the files or directories, and then print the absolute path of that file.

Comment: I can't By the FileSystemRegistry I get only one root, the "c:/". But that doesn't work and instead it throws an exception. So I can't really list any files without fileconnection. Or maybe I just don't understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suspect that your problem is that you are trying to write a file in a location your MIDlet isn't allowed to write to.

My guess is that you can read "c:/" just enough to figure out what its subfolders are. You can't create a file or a subfolder.

However, browse through c: subfolders and there should be a location somewhere where you can create a subfolder and/or a file.

Of course, all this assumes that your MIDlet is signed with a certificate that puts it in a security domain allowing good enough file system access.

Comment: I have already figured it out. What you are saying is true. I could have used open("file:///MemoryStick/) instead of direct opening file. 
The problem with accessing MemoryStick was because of usb connection to the computer, which was blocking the MemoryStick root for the phone. 
Certificates is a pain, but good phones (like this one) allow you to manage permissions.